# chrome extension и getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){
var objList = document.getElementsByClassName("anyClass");
alert(objList.length)
})
```

По клику на значок расширения должен выводиться алерт, показывающий количество элементов на странице с классом. Но возвращается всегда 0.
Если в консоли прописать

```
var objList = document.getElementsByClassName("anyClass")
```

то список создаётся. Если через расширение то нет. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: ищешь не в том документе

Comment: То есть код выполняется для самой кнопки расширения (browserAction)? Подскажи тогда, пожалуйста, что я пропустил чтобы код выполнялся для открытой вкладки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так, не тестил:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){

  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    code: `                        
       var objList = document.getElementsByClassName("anyClass");
       alert(objList.length)`
  });
})
```